# Can Extragradient Method Be Expressed with Proximal Operators Steps?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

As we know, for solving saddle point problems, forward-backward algorithm is generally not guaranteed to converge. But extragradient method converge [Structured Prediction via the Extragradient
Method](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~taskar/pubs/extragrad_long.pdf)

Suppose $L(w,z)$ is a convex in $w$-concave in $z$ function. Can we express extragradient,
\begin{align}
w^{k+1/2}&=P_{W}(w^k-\beta \bigtriangledown_w L(w^k,z^k))\cr
z^{k+1/2}&=P_{Z}(z^k+\beta \bigtriangledown_z L(w^k,z^k))\cr
w^{k+1}&=P_{W}(w^k-\beta \bigtriangledown_w L(w^{(k+1/2)},z^{(k+1/2)}))\cr
z^{k+1}&=P_{Z}(z^k+\beta \bigtriangledown_z L(w^{(k+1/2)},z^{(k+1/2)}))\cr
\end{align}
with only proximal steps? I mean without using gradient of function $L$.
Sorry for asking the same question on mathoverflow.

Comment: MO version of the question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239992/can-the-extragradient-method-be-computed-only-based-on-proximal-steps.

Comment: A gradient step is a proximal step for a smooth function. So, yes you rewrite your algorithm only using proximal steps. But this doesn't really say anything. Maybe you can tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a saddle point problem. For some reason I have to solve optimization with respect to one problem using proximal step and it isn't easy for me to compute gradient. So, when I want to solve saddle point problem the only algorithms that  work and has guaranteed convergence are all based on Korpelevich's extragradient (HPE of saviter and monteiro).

Comment: It is interesting for me how to solve the third and forth steps using a proximal step.

Comment: @dohmatob, would you please tell how to rewrite problem using only proximal step? Thank you.

Comment: This is research-level question, namely: solving structured prediction via gradient-free proximal method. See my anwser below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a refinement the HPE paper [here](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~monteiro/publications/tech_reports/saddle_v4.pdf). Consider the problem model in equation (7). In the jargon of the latter paper, the problem you're trying to solve corresponds to a Nash-equilibrium problem with $\Psi_1(z, w) = -\Psi_2(z, w) :=  \sum_{i}w^TF_iz_i$ (a billinear form), $g_1(z) := \sum_{i}c_i^Tz_i$, and $g_2(w) := \sum_{i}w^TF_iy^{(i)} + I_{\|.\| \le 1}$. Now invoke algorithm T-BD (or Teng's BD-HPE; see the same paper). It should be trivial to compute the proximal operators of the $g_k$'s.

Comment: But my problem is not in bilinear form and I cannot compute the gradient with respect to one variable say $z$. In that algorithm, there is a gradient with respect to both variables.

Comment: OK, then I'm lost. Could you precisely write down the objective you're trying to minimize-maximize. I assumed you were solving problem (5) of the structured prediction paper you referred to. This is the problem also referred to in section 4 of your reference paper.

Comment: My objective is $\min_{x,X} \max_y  \big(x^Ty- y^T(X\odot A) y\big)$. It is linear convex in the first variable and concave quadratic in the second.